# Is it possible to shorten individual columns in pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a 1000x40 data frame where I am fitting each column with a function. 
For this, I am normalizing the data to run from 0 to 1 and then I fit each column by this sigmoidal function,

```
def func_2_2(x, slope, halftime):
    yfit = 0 + 1 / (1+np.exp(-slope*(x-halftime)))
    return yfit

# inital guesses for function
slope_guess = 0.5
halftime_guess = 100

# Construct initial guess array
p0 = np.array([slope_guess, halftime_guess])

# set up curve fit
col_params = {}
for col in dfnormalized.columns:
    x = df.iloc[:,0]
    y = dfnormalized[col].values
    popt = curve_fit(func_2_2, x, y, p0=p0, maxfev=10000)
    col_params[col] = popt[0]
```

This code is working well for me, but the data fitting would physically make more sense if I could cut each column shorter on an individual basis. The data plateaus for some of the columns already at e.g. 500 data points, and for others at 700 to virtually 1. I would like to implement a function where I simply cut off the column after it arrives at 1 (and there is no need to have another 300 or more data points to be included in the fit). I thought of cutting off 50 data points starting from the end if their average number is close to 1. I would dump them, until I arrive at the data that I want in be included.

When I try to add a function where I try to determine the average of the last 50 datapoints with e.g. passing the y-vector from above like this:

```
def cutdata(y)
lastfifty = y.tail(50).average
```

I receive the error message

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tail'
```

Does my approach make sense and is it possible within the data frame? 
- Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

`print(y)`

gives

`[0.00203105 0.00407113 0.00145333 ... 0.99178177 0.97615621 0.97236191]`

Comment: Can you `print(y)` and share that?

Comment: The error message I am receiving is acutally 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tail'
Thanks and sorry for that!

Comment: No problem. Thank you for finding and making the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the use of [pd.Series.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html), which will give you an `np.ndarray` instead of a `pd.Series`.

A conservative change to your code would move the use of `.values` into the `curve_fit` call. It may not even be necessary there, since a `pd.Series` is already a `np.ndarray` for most purposes.

```py
for col in dfnormalized.columns:
    x = df.iloc[:,0]
    y = dfnormalized[col]  # No more .values here.
    popt = curve_fit(func_2_2, x, y.values, p0=p0, maxfev=10000)
    col_params[col] = popt[0]
```

The essential part is highlighted by the comment, which is that your `y` variable will remain a `pd.Series`. Then you can get the average of the last observations.

```
y.tail(50).mean()
```

Comment: Fantastic! As suggested, the .values is not necessary. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that helped!